# How do you remove old custom Sametime status messages from IBM Notes 9.0 Social Edition?

Tags: lotus-notes

How do you remove old custom IBM Notes Sametime status messages?

Comment: Please clarify :-) What "old custom statuses" from what "drop down"?

Comment: I think, he talks about Sametime- Status from the embedded Sametime Client

Answer (score 1):

Edit the XML file:
C:\notes\data\workspace.metadata.plugins\com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.login\CN=Username.xml

where "CN=Username" will be your name.

There several xml tags used for the different statuses:

Active `<activeText>`

Away `<awayText>`

In a Meeting `<inMtgText>`

Do not Disturb `<dndText>`